# Browser-Side templates with src

Tags: jquery, html, templates, backbone.js

Recently I've been exploring [Backbone](http://backbonejs.com), and they do encourage using a template engine.

Now, I've got a bunch of html files that I want to display using that, and I will most likely have to edit them often in the development stage. The most tutorials I read recomment something like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="template1">
    <ul>
        <li>Hic sunt dracones</li>
    </ul>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    template = $('#template1').html();
<script>
```

So I'd like to know if this can be made to work with the `src`-attribute to include the template files. Or, if not, what is the usual approach to load template files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `src` for this is not possible.
You could include a JavaScript file though which is generated on the server from separate template files; with PHP it could be as simple as this:

```
<?php
$templates = array(
    'foo' => file_get_contents('foo.html'),
    'bar' => file_get_contents('bar.html'),
);
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
echo 'var templates = ' . json_encode($templates);
?>
```

Loading this file with a `<script>` tag then gives you an object `templates` where you can acccess the various templates via `templates.foo`, `templates.bar`, etc.